# Have I understood the shunting-yard wrong

Tags: c++, algorithm, operator-precedence, shunting-yard

can you tell me if I understood it wrong, or the example is wrong?

I will write the associativity right after the operator. 'r' stand for right and 'l' stands for left. The expression wont have paranthesis.

`-r *r 8 5 +r /r 20 4 /l *r 5 8 10`

The result given is this:

`8 5 *r 20 4 /r 5 8 *r 10 /l +r -r`

What I dont understand is, when I reach `5 8 10` my stack at this moment would be `*r /l +r -r`. I read 5, it is not an operator, so I print it. I read 8, not an operator -> print. And then I read 10, not an operator -> print. Why *r is popped out of the stack before reading 10?

Comment: What example are you talking about? Either the `-r *r 8 5 +r /r 20 4 /l *r 5 8 10` isn't your input, or you must be using some other algorithm than the shunting yard algorithm. Either way, it's hard to understand the question.

Comment: Shunting yard algorithm parses infix expressions. Your input doesn't look like a valid infix expression.

Comment: @n.m. i see what i asked now :D, can you tell me how to transform prefixex pression to postfix?

Comment: Prefix operators have no associativity.